# Is it always safe to call an parent's version of an overriden method without knowing whether the parent override it?

Tags: c++, inheritance

Consider the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

class Ancestor1 {
  public:
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};
class Ancestor2 : public Ancestor1 {
  public:
    virtual void foo() {
      printf("I am ancestor 2\n");
    }
};
class Ancestor3 : public Ancestor2 {
  public:
    virtual void foo() {
      printf("I am ancestor 3\n");
    }
};

class Ancestor4 : public Ancestor3 { };
class Descendant : public Ancestor4 {
  public:
    virtual void foo() {
      printf("I am Descendant\n");
      Ancestor4::foo();
    }
};

int main(){
  Descendant d;
  d.foo();
}
```

When I run this program, the output is the following:

```
I am Descendant
I am ancestor 3
```

The actual behavior matches the intended behavior, insofar as I want:

- `Descendant::foo()` to invoke its parent's version of `foo()` if the parent defines `foo()` and
- `Descendant::foo()` to invoke its grandparent's version of `foo()` if the parent does not define it.

As long as there is no multiple-inheritance conflict, can I always call  `Ancestor4::foo();` and expect that the run-time resolver to find the first class in the inheritance chain that defines `foo()` and call `foo()` on that?

Comment: Do you really want to `language-lawyer` this? Yes, it's safe, and the calls with `ClassName::` are resolved at compile-time.

Comment: Removed the tag.

Comment: and I almost met it halfway :D I have trouble finding reference in standard which explicitly says what  is ging on with pointer-to-meber of virtual functions. The rest is well-described in `expr.call`. (and now I expect user named LanguageLawyer to pop here)

Comment: Side note : <stdio.h> is a legacy "C" header so you probably don't need it

Comment: Define "safe".   The behaviour you see is the behaviour that is required for your example. `d.foo()` will resolve to a call of `Descendant::foo()`, which explicitly calls `Ancestor4::foo()` which (since `Ancestor4::foo()` is neither declared nor defined, but `Ancestor3` overrides the `foo()` it inherits from `Ancestor2`) resolves to the closest base version i.e.  to `Ancestor3::foo()`.      An explicit call of `Ancestor4::foo()` cannot resolve to a call of `Descendant::foo()` since Descendant is not a base of `Ancestor4`.

Comment: @Peter By "safe" I mean simply that I can rely on the observed behavior in any compiling class hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's safe.

> can I always call `Ancestor4::foo();` and expect that the run-time resolver...

Calls with `ClassName::` are always resolved at compile-time (not counting member pointers).

Answer (score 0):

There were some ancient implementations which due bugs in translator were allowing to write a call in template code or "take address" of pure virtual function. Note that taking member pointer is legal, it *is never NULL* and has *always "same value" for same virtual function* in same "family" of classes. Pointer to virtual member is convertible to a pointer to member of derived class, and can be used to call overriding function of derived class

```
struct CommonAncestor {
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

template <int i> class Ancestor;

template <> struct Ancestor<0> : CommonAncestor { 
    void foo() override {
      std::cout << "Pointer to pure foo: " << std::boolalpha << &CommonAncestor::foo << std::endl;
      // CommonAncestor::foo(); // either does not compile or doesn't link
    } 
};

template <int i> struct Ancestor : Ancestor<i-1> { 
    void foo() override { 
        std::cout << "Pointer to Ancestor<" << i-1 << ">:foo " << std::boolalpha << &Ancestor<i-1>::foo << std::endl; 
        Ancestor<i-1>::foo();
     } 
};

// Ancestor<2> got no override
template <> struct Ancestor<2> : Ancestor<1>{ };

int main() {
    Ancestor<3> f;
    void (Ancestor<3>::* fptr)(void) = &CommonAncestor::foo;
    f.foo();
    (f.*fptr)(); // safe, calls Ancestor<3>::foo
    
    void (CommonAncestor::* ptr)(void) = &CommonAncestor::foo;
    ((CommonAncestor*){0}->*ptr)(); // UB because CommonAncestor cannot exist
}
```

With a compliant implementation you'll get a link error if you comment `Ancestor<0>::foo`
declaration out and usually a compile-time error if you try to call `CommonAncestor::foo` directly from class context.

Some old implementations treated the latter as an UB. Formally the only case where it is possible in ISO C++ context is when program is built with an ODR breach - one of definition of class is missing override or had changed  number of function members in it, while another was used to compile the call. This is the usual source of "pure function call" exceptions from Microsoft or GCC implementations.

Using a pointer to `CommonAncestor::foo` on any *existing* instance class for a call is well-formed as `&CommonAncestor::foo` is convertible to `void (Ancestor<i>::*) (void)` and results in call to the most-inherited version of `foo` as per rule for call expression (https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.call).

> 5. Calling a function through an expression whose function type E is
>    different from the function type F of the called function's definition
>    results in undefined behavior unless the type “pointer to F” can be
>    converted to the type “pointer to E” via a function pointer conversion

> 2. If the selected function is non-virtual, or if the id-expression in
>    the class member access expression is a qualified-id, that function is
>    called. Otherwise, its final overrider in the dynamic type of the
>    object expression is called; such a call is referred to as a virtual
>    function call.

A special case is finalization of virtual functon:

```
template <> struct Ancestor<2> : Ancestor<1>{  void foo() final {} };
template <> struct Ancestor<3> : Ancestor<2>{  };
```

Code above still will work but an `Ancestor<i>` with `i` greator than 3 wouldn't be able to exist. It's not permitted to re-declare same function again.

What this means for the wants

- Have `Descendant::foo()` to invoke its parent's version of `foo()` if the parent defines `foo()`, and
- Have `Descendant::foo()` to invoke its grandparent's version of `foo()` if the parent does not define it:

That's how language acts by definition. If a "parent" or "grandparent" have a base class which defines a virtual `foo()`, they also considered to have `foo` defined, *there is no direct way* to detect the absense of re-definition, for the pointers to member are the same. The only way to remove it is to declare it `final` AND `private` in base class, which cannot be undone later. Expected type reflection in future standard may change that.